# Regex returns true on partial match

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I'am trying to implement a custom url validation.

Regex:

```
^((ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/|~/|/)([\w]+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z]{1}([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,5}))(:[\d]{1,5})?((/?\w+/)+|/?)(\w+\.[\w]{3,4})?((\?\w+=\w+)?(&\w+=\w+)*)?
```

Examples: http://regexr.com?36crr

If I add a watch on `RegExp.IsMatch` this returns true. It should be false like in the examples above
[image]

stringToTest: "http://www.test@test.be"

RegExp

```
^((ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/|~/|/)([\w]+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z]{1}([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,5}))(:[\d]{1,5})?((/?\w+/)+|/?)(\w+\.[\w]{3,4})?((\?\w+=\w+)?(&\w+=\w+)*)?
```

Can anyone help me?

The $ sign did it
Thx

Comment: Add `$` at the end of the regex string?

Comment: You could use the [`Uri.IsWellFormedUriString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx) method to check that the URI is well formed.

Comment: Why are you escaping sometimes `/` and sometimes not?